# Record create and Update time not stored in localtime django

Tags: django, timezone

I have a model "Member" where there are two fields "created_at" and "updated_at".
Originally, they were defined as below :

```
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
```

my settings.py have **USE_TZ = True** and TIME_ZONE = "America/New_York".

I have a custom middleware defined to activate the timezone as selected by the user.

```
current_tz = pytz.timezone("<user defined timezone>")
timezone.activate(current_tz)
```

Then, I update the fields to store the user localtime:

```
created_at = models.DateTimeField(default= lambda: timezone.localtime(timezone.now()), null=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(default= lambda: timezone.localtime(timezone.now()), null=True)
```

Now, when I update the Member record and check the **updated_at** time, its showing the same UTC timezone instead of the localtime of the user.

Is it that django always stores datetime values in DB in UTC or am I missing something here

Comment: This code will only ever use the localtime of the server, not the user.

Comment: I have edited my question to mention a middleware that's in place to activate the timezone as per the user's selected timezone. So, how to make it use the user's localtime not the server ?

Comment: Fair enough. But this still seems like a bad idea. Why do you want to store the local time, rather than - as explicitly recommended [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/timezones/) - storing UTC and converting on output?

Comment: So, there is no need to update the created_at and updated_at fields and just convert there value to localtime while accessing them.

Answer (score 1):

All your requirement should focus on `USE_TZ = True`.

If you set `USE_TZ = True`, the DateTimeField stores the UTC time. 
If you comment the `USE_TZ = True` in your settings.py, you can get what you want.

But in project, you should better always open the USE_TZ, if open USE_TZ, all the store or  internal processing even print, are UTC timezone. when you shows in the templates, it is quite convenient for [time format conversion](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/database-functions/).